# Crystal Reports - two print formats

Tags: printing, crystal-reports, formatting

I have two ways to print a report, into a PDF or on letterhead.

Is it possible to have in a report a customization so that in the PDF I have a logo in the header, and on the letterhead I don't have that logo in the header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a parameter with a boolean to the report. Something like IsPDF and then in the header Click on the Format Graphic (assuming it is an image) of the logo and then choose the X2 across from the Suppress checkbox.

[image]

From there you can write code that will suppress the graphic when the IsPDF paramater is False and not suppress when the IsPDF is True.

```
IF {?IsPDF} = True Then
False
```

Edit: After writing this out I think I would actually make the boolean parameter be IsLetterHead so that when it was True it would be consistent with the True in the Suppress. In other words

```
IF {?IsLetterHead} = True Then
True
```

Comment: An observation: i don't have the possibility to define if it is to be pdf or letterhead, ie, i only have two buttons, one where i can preview and save the document as pdf, and another where i can save to physical printer, on the letterhead. In this case the procedure maybe is not the same, right?

Comment: Do you have the ability to modify the code behind the button? If so you can pass the parameter from there into the report. Otherwise I think you are asking whether or not you can make the Report itself make the determination of whether it is a PDF or not and then suppress the header (or not) based on that. Is that correct?

Comment: I can't modify the code behind in the button and it's correct what you wrote. The best of the best is to do like an automatic supress when i click in the print button. Maybe some specific code to determine that a print job is being caled.